# Breaking down a map[chararray] in pig latin

Tags: apache-pig

I am very new to pig latin so excuse any ignorance in the following question.  I have inherited some code that does essentially the following:

```
USERS = LOAD 'hbase://some_table' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('s:*', '-caster HBaseBinaryConverter --limit some_limit') AS (user_map:map[chararray]);
```

Now if I do a dump of `USERS` I get something like the following (fake data)

```
([n1#{"s":{"added": 1430668638000, "lastseen": 1430668638000, "expires": 1433260638000}},n2#{"s":{"added": 1430668638000, "lastseen": 1430668638000, "expires": 1433692638000}},n22#{"segment":{"added": 1430668638000, "lastseen": 1430668638000, "expires": 1433260638000}},n3#{"s":{"added": 1430668638000, "lastseen": 1430668638000, "expires": 1433692638000}},n4#{"segment":{"added": 1430668638000, "lastseen": 1430668638000, "expires": 1433692638000}}])
([n8#{"s":{"added": 1428792426000, "lastseen": 1428792426000, "expires": 1431816426000}},n9#{"segment":{"added": 1428792426000, "lastseen": 1428792426000, "expires": 1431816426000}},n11#{"segment":{"added": 1428792426000, "lastseen": 1428792426000, "expires": 1431816426000}}])
```

Essentially I want to get at the `n*` values in the output.  But I am not exactly sure how to break them down from this schema.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To explain my question a bit more, perhaps my understanding of the `map:[chararray]` schema (and how to manipulate it) is lacking

**EDIT** My desired expected output would be storing all of `n*` information into a variable called `TITLES`.  This way when I do `DUMP TITLES` I would get the following

```
n1#
n2# ...
```

Comment: Share the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to answer my own question by writing a python UDF.  In Pig the call looks like this

```
N_S = FOREACH USERS GENERATE my_udfs.translate_map(user_map)
```

My python udf looks something like

```
@outputSchema("doc:chararray")
def translate_map(input):

    n_str = ""
    for k, v in input.items():

        n_str += str(key)
        n_str += " "

    return n_str
```